# how to convert object data type into float in python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyC1y.png)

-Here is my dataset contain the special character, so my question is how to remove that A^ symbol from the Quantity column..
- after removing that special symbol from data, how i can convert this column to float type..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**:

You can use `replace` and `to_numeric`:

```
df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Quantity.str.replace('Â',''))
```

**example**:

```
>>> df
  Quantity  data
0    0.1 Â     1
1    0.2 Â     2

df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Quantity.str.replace('Â',''))

>>> df
   Quantity  data
0       0.1     1
1       0.2     2
```

**Method 2**:

Alternatively, since your Â is always preceded by a space, you can use `split` and take the first item:

```
df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'].str.split().str[0])
```

Comment: Unable to parse string "0.1  " at position 0

Comment: Funny, I don't get that error. But try using `strip` to get rid of the trailing whitespace: `pd.to_numeric(df.Quantity.str.replace('Â','').str.strip())`